# How to Loop each row, if column is this value, then insert certain values into another column

Tags: excel, loops, vbscript, excel-formula

Originally the values on column C on the excel file have no values at all. This is the logic I want to do, If values is num1 on column B, set 100 on column C, else if values is num2 on column B, set 200 on column C, else 300 on column C. My current codes now only can do only for one row.

That;s why I need a loop, to go row by row and do it, it will stop until it reaches row 11 which is the last row of values. I have pasted what I have tried using the looping codes at the end below and it doesn't work. Pls help me correct my loop, or maybe my formula have some problem since I don't know if i insert the counter variable in the formula correctly a not.

**Current output that generate values in the C column using my current working codes.**
[image]

**Ideal output that I wanted to achieve using codes.**
[image]

**My current codes that generate the values in the C column for the first screenshot above**

```
 Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
    Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

Set objFSO2 = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objWorkbook2 = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("D:\Shared\tempname\test\test2.xlsx")

              '********** Instantiate the Workbook.Worksheets **********
              '               object to open a particular
              '                    Excel Worksheet
              Set objWorksheet2 = objWorkbook2.Worksheets(c_FirstWksht)

                Dim cellObj

                set cellObj = objWorksheet2.cells(3, 3)

                cellObj.formula = "=IF(B3=""NUM1"",""100"",IF(B3=""NUM2"",""200"",""300""))"


                Set objWorkbook2 = nothing
                 objExcel.Quit


                        '********** Exit the Script **********

                        Wscript.Quit
```

**What I have tried for looping the codes and it doesn't work**

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

Set objFSO2 = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objWorkbook2 = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("D:\Shared\tempname\test\test2.xlsx")
      '********** Instantiate the Workbook.Worksheets **********
      '               object to open a particular
      '                    Excel Worksheet
      Set objWorksheet2 = objWorkbook2.Worksheets(c_FirstWksht)

        Dim cellObj
        Dim counter
        counter = 3
        Do Until counter = 13 
        set cellObj = objWorksheet2.cells(counter, 3)

        cellObj.formula = "=IF("& counter &"=""NUM1"",""100"",IF("& counter &"=""NUM2"",""200"",""300""))"
        Loop

        Set objWorkbook2 = nothing
         objExcel.Quit




                '********** Exit the Script **********



                Wscript.Quit
```

**I got this error using the looping codes that I have tried.**
[image]

**Error following user3907047 codes**
[image]

Comment: Why aren't you doing this all in SQL?  Application SQL rendering takes much longer than it all being done in SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modify like that:

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

Set objFSO2 = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objWorkbook2 = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("e:\0\xx\Fax.xlsx")

Set objWorksheet2 = objWorkbook2.Worksheets(1)

    Dim cellObj
    Dim counter
    counter = 3
    Do Until counter = 12
        set cellObj = objWorksheet2.cells(counter, 3)
        cellObj.formula = "=IF(B"& counter &"=""NUM1"",""100"",IF(B"& counter &"=""NUM2"",""200"",""300""))"
        counter = counter + 1
    Loop
objWorkbook2.save
Set objWorkbook2 = nothing
objExcel.Quit
Wscript.Quit
```

**Error Found :-)**
1) In the formula you forget the name of the column "B"
2) you don't increase the counter
3) you don't save the workbook
4) the until cicle it's not a good job. If you change the number of rows, you need to change the Script.
For the point 4 I prefer a code like:

```
    Do Until counter = 1200
       if objWorksheet2.range("B" & counter).value = "" then 
          counter = 1200
        else
          set cellObj = objWorksheet2.cells(counter, 3)
          cellObj.formula = "=IF(B"& counter &"=""NUM1"",""100"",IF(B"& counter &"=""NUM2"",""200"",""300""))"
          counter = counter + 1
        end if
    Loop
```

it's more usable...

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit basic....but should do the trick:

```
Sub test()
Dim nrows, ncols As Single
Dim CWS, CWB As String

CWB = ActiveWorkbook.Name
CWS = Workbooks(CWB).ActiveSheet.Name
nrows = 2
ncols = 2

Do Until Workbooks(CWB).Sheets(CWS).Cells(nrows, ncols) = ""

    If Workbooks(CWB).Sheets(CWS).Cells(nrows, ncols) = "NUM1" Then
        Workbooks(CWB).Sheets(CWS).Cells(nrows, ncols + 1) = "100"
    ElseIf Workbooks(CWB).Sheets(CWS).Cells(nrows, ncols) = "NUM2" Then
        Workbooks(CWB).Sheets(CWS).Cells(nrows, ncols + 1) = "200"
    Else
        Workbooks(CWB).Sheets(CWS).Cells(nrows, ncols + 1) = "300"
    End If

    nrows = nrows + 1
Loop


End Sub
```

I hope this helps more, I tried to implement my loop logic with your second example which I think should work:

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

Set objFSO2 = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objWorkbook2 = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("D:\Shared\tempname\test\test2.xlsx")
  '********** Instantiate the Workbook.Worksheets **********
  '               object to open a particular
  '                    Excel Worksheet
  Set objWorksheet2 = objWorkbook2.Worksheets(c_FirstWksht)

    Dim nrows, ncols
    nrows = 2
    ncols = 2
   Do Until Workbooks(objWorkbook2).Sheets(objWorksheet2).Cells(nrows, ncols) = ""

If Workbooks(objWorkbook2).Sheets(objWorksheet2).Cells(nrows, ncols) = "NUM1" Then
    Workbooks(objWorkbook2).Sheets(objWorksheet2).Cells(nrows, ncols + 1) = "100"
ElseIf Workbooks(objWorkbook2).Sheets(objWorksheet2).Cells(nrows, ncols) = "NUM2" Then
    Workbooks(objWorkbook2).Sheets(objWorksheet2).Cells(nrows, ncols + 1) = "200"
Else
    Workbooks(objWorkbook2).Sheets(objWorksheet2).Cells(nrows, ncols) = "300"
End If

nrows = nrows + 1
Loop

    Set objWorkbook2 = nothing
     objExcel.Quit




            '********** Exit the Script **********



            Wscript.Quit
```

Comment: user3907047 I have error at the Dim line. screenshot above. I would prefer if you can help me correct my codes that I have provided tho if u knew instead of giving me a whole new set of codes.

Comment: I removed the as single and as string, and that error is gone. But I still have the error of renaming the worksheets all those stuff... not sure how to rename it to mine tho @user3907047

Comment: I'm not used to the editor you're using for the VBA script...I'm used to doing this in excel itself and not calling it from a command prompt.  Looking at your code though, the reason the first example you gave isn't working is because you're not moving beyond cells(3,3). The second example also won't work because you set "counter" to 3 but don't increment it during the loop and the formula you wrote isn't proper for excel because your IF statement is referencing a value for Counter and not a real excel cell or reference. I hope some of these pointers help.

Comment: Thanks @user3907047 I did it using your codes, renameing it to my worksheets names. But do u know how to correct my codes(the one which have a counter). Would like to learn wats the problem. oh I just saw your above comments(reading it now)